# need to download .zip souce code for mytracks opensource app from http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/

Tags: android

i want to downloaad the .zip source code files for mytracks opensource app for android but find no download link and am only able to create clone from http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/

Please tell me or send me a link for the source code for mytracks in .zip format ?

Comment: Question, does not belong here.

Answer (score 2):

If the developer has not provided a source archive, then you'll have to generate one yourself.

However, you can still easily get the source code by setting up and configuring [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/), and then executing the following in the command line:

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/
```

This will download the source code to your current working directory.